# VLAN setup for DSL modem and NAT box

Tags: vlan

I have a home network with a managed switch. For better security, I'd like to put the DSL modem/gateway my ISP gave me on a separate VLAN, then do NAT for my local network on another machine.

For the DSL modem, I think this just means I'll put it on one VLAN (this should mean I can put it in routing mode where it exposes my public IP). For other machines, I put them on another (or can I just leave them on the default VLAN?). For the NAT machine, things are a little more complicated. Do I configure the switch to have that port on both VLANs, then set up subinterfaces in the OS?

My main goal is that all machines other than the NAT box shouldn't be aware they're even on a VLAN, and plugging in a device to a switch port other than the NAT box's or the modem's should be like plugging into a normal home network.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. Unfortunately, NE is a site for network professionals to ask and provide answers about professional networks. Questions about home networks and consumer devices are considered off topic by this community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: I completely understand what you're trying to do, but VLAN setup on a managed switch is a bit outside the scope of typical home networking.

Comment: if you think that is the case, feel free to ask on [Meta](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/), referencing this question. This will allow the community to provide better answers than I can in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the details of which switch you're using, the general approach to solve this would be to stick your DSL modem on a port in access mode (untagged/tagging removed packets from a single VLAN only) with a VLAN membership say of 1000, while all your internal machines would have a different VLAN membership (say 1001). Your NAT box would then connect into your switch in trunk mode, with membership in both VLANs. You could opt to make one VLAN the default untagged one, or neither - your choice (if your switch permits this).

Within the OS of your NAT box, setup for routing between the VLAN interfaces. For Linux, assuming that you're using tagged VLANs as described above for the trunk port which is on eth0, you will have to perform NAT on the eth0.1001/eth0.1000 interfaces. If you choose to make, say VLAN 1001, the default untagged VLAN for that trunk port, then you will need to NAT eth0/eth0.1000.

Comment: The switch is a Netgear M4100-D10-POE, so I think they also call it "access mode" and "trunk mode." I noticed you picked 1000 and 1001. Any good conventions for picking VLAN ids? Should I avoid the default 1?

Comment: There isn't any standard convention for picking VLAN IDs that I'm aware of. I personally pick a base number, 1000 in this case, and increment for each VLAN I need. Sometimes, I prefer to pick different base numbers for different VLAN purposes, e.g. "operations" - 100, "research" - 200, "guest" - 300 etc. As for the default VLAN, some argument could be made on the principle of security to not use it, but many measures like disabling unused ports, using port security, 802.1x etc. can address it to varying degrees of efficacy/comfort.